# Weird result upon splicing an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Please see the below code and it's corresponding output when ran on chrome console.

```
var x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
var y = x;
console.log(y.length);
x.splice(1,1);
console.log(y.length);
console.log(x.length);
```

The output is as follows:
`8`
`7`
`7`

My query is since I've initialized the variable `y` before splicing `x`, then why the `y` is getting spliced automatically. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Because when you assign `x` to `y` you pass a reference of the object, so you dont copy the item. `x` and `y` are the same "object"

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, primitive types are copied by value and reference types are copied by reference. 
More info here: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/web/jscript/ch09_03.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

your code is reference to array. try this `var y = [...x];`

Comment: I would say this does provide an answer, it's just not well explained. Try explaining why that solution would work.